# Close/cancel button on image dialog box is not working in WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, image, dialog, lightbox

I am working on our Wordpress Website Page that has a close button for image lightbox dialog box view. This close button works good on our development site, and stopped working on live site. It seems like an issue with script but I am not able to locate the exact spot of the issue.

Please check the URLs below and compare live site with the dev site. *The problem is with the images in the table of contents.*

Dev Site - http://sensoft1.yourdevsite.ca/products/noggin/overview/

Live Site - https://www.sensoft.ca/products/noggin/overview/

Please let me know if you can help me figure out the solution.

Comment: If you compare source code of these webs you will notice that live site has not got `<a class="lightbox-close" href="#close"></a> <a class="lightbox-close overlay_kill" href="#close"></a>`

Comment: Tomaz, I notice that difference. Though, these are not part of HTML content. I believe classes like 'lightbox-close' are controlled by JavaScript. HTML contents are written under WordPress page. And they look like this - <td class="tg-031e"><a class="lightbox" href="#img1"><img src="http://sensoft1.yourdevsite.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Noggin-100.jpg" alt="Noggin-100" /></a></td>